# How do I navigate to Mouse & Trackpad in Accessibility Settings with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility

I used Accessibility Inspector to try and help me figure this out but I wasn't quite able to get it. I'm navigating to the Accessibility pane but after that I am having trouble navigating to Mouse & Trackpad, or any other menu item for that matter.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"

    -- part that I am having trouble with
    tell table 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
    select row 1
    end tell

end tell
```

[image: What the actual GUI looks like]

[image: This is just some of the info that the Accessibility Inspector gave me]

Comment: What settings are you trying to change? Perhaps it would be simpler to determine which .plist files need to be modified using the `defaults write` terminal command to change the settings instead of figuring out the scripting for the GUI interface. Some plist file suspects in ~/Library/Preferences: `com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad`, `com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse`, `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse`, `com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad`, `com.apple.preference.trackpad`. You can see what settings can be changed by using the `defaults read` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need UI Scripting to be able to do this.  System Preferences has an applescript dictionary that allows you to open up specific preference screens (panes) and specific items in the table (anchors).

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Mouse" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    activate
end tell
```

Will open up the mouse and trackpad section. I found this by looking at the AppleScript dictionary for System Preferences, and some googling took me to an [excellent discussion of using these commands](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html).

Comment: While this does open System Preferences to the Mouse & Trackpad under Accessibility the window doesn't have focus and can be behind other windows. I'd add `activate` after the `reveal anchor ...` line.

Comment: Great point. I added that.